# Migrate Win10 SSD from BIOS to UEFI motherboard

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bios, uefi

I have a system SSD with Windows 10. Old motherboard (P5Q) had only BIOS and everything booted and boots just fine.

New MB (Z170-P) has UEFI and I've tried tons of options up to RAID configurations to boot up old SSD but had unexpected shutdowns at different stages of booting (up to login screen and few seconds beyond).

Can I safely remap (and backup) my SSD for it to be able to launch on a new motherboard?

Or is new motherboards message "restarted to prevent electric something" accurate and reboots have nothing to do with OS? I could sit minutes in UEFI screen and reboots only occurred whilst trying to boot up Windows.

I can try and make Linux USB stick and try remapping from there if it helps. I also have access to Acronis True Image 2017 if it's necessary.

It would really help if I didn't have to reinstall everything and/or create new user as when you use Windows native utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem apparently is not related the the boot mode, but what's installed on the SSD. If you have your UEFI set in legacy mode, BIOS HDD/SSD will boot just fine, but since you changed your MB you have to reinstall the OS, since it will most likely crash or experience other anomalies if you don't. In your specific case, a windows repair could help; it could fix the system/MB-driver related files and keep everything you have intact.